# Setting hook with using react js map and reducer causes code underneath to not be ran

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a main table that has several different types of account entries. To split them I created hooks and used this to separate them:

```
    const [assetAccounts, setAssetAccounts] = useState([]);
    const [equityAccounts, setEquityAccounts] = useState([]);
    const [liabilityAccounts, setLiabilityAccounts] = useState([]);

    const [assetsTotal, setAssetTotal] = useState();
    const [liabilityTotal, setLiabilityTotal] = useState();
    const [equityTotal , setEquityTotal] = useState();

           setAssetAccounts(accountsListJson.filter(accountsListJson =>               
            accountsListJson.journal_account_category.toString().toLowerCase().includes("assets")
            ))

            setEquityAccounts(accountsListJson.filter(accountsListJson =>               
            accountsListJson.journal_account_category.toString().toLowerCase().includes("equity")
            ))

            setLiabilityAccounts(accountsListJson.filter(accountsListJson =>               
            accountsListJson.journal_account_category.toString().toLowerCase().includes("liabilities")
            ))
```

These work fine but the problem is with finding the total of each one. Whenever I use any of these to set the total:

```
 setAssetTotal(assetAccounts.map(assetAccount => assetAccount.journal_balance).reduce((a, b) => parseInt(a) + parseInt(b)));

 setEquityTotal(equityAccounts.map(equityAccount => equityAccount.journal_balance).reduce((a, b) => parseInt(a) + parseInt(b)));

setLiabilityTotal(liabilityAccounts.map(liabilityAccount => liabilityAccount.journal_balance).reduce((a, b) => parseInt(a) + parseInt(b)));
```

## Problem

The code underneath any of the set total functions will not run. For example if I put these set functions  after setting the three accounts, only setAssetTotal will actually set its value. Is there a problem with the formatting or something? I'm not sure why the code underneath will not run

Answer (score 0):

`.map` will return an array instead of a number. You must use `.reduce` directly. You can use a simple reusable function to find the totals like this.

```
const findTotal = (total) => {
  return total.reduce((a, b, index) => {
    return parseFloat(a.journal_balance) + parseFloat(b.journal_balance)
  },0)
}

setAssetTotal(findTotal(assetAccounts))

setEquityTotal(findTotal(equityAccounts))

setLiabilityTotal(findTotal(liabilityAccounts))
```